# How write/read binary data from PostgreSQL?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, binary

I want write/read hashes in binary format (varbinary/binary/etc in PostgreSQL and byte[] in C#) via direct SQL query (SQLCommand), but don't know how do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Devart as ADO.NET provider for PostgreSQL and then do something similar to:
http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/Devart.Data.PostgreSql~Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlBlob.html

Comment: I'm connecting to PostgreSQL through Npgsql